# NgxPermissions not working with Lazy Loaded Module

Tags: angular, permissions, angular6, lazy-loading

When adding ngx-permissions to my project, compilation error happens. My code contains multiple lazy-loaded modules and each one makes use of `*ngxPermissionsOnly`

Tried importing `NgxPermissionsModule`, `NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()`, `NgxPermissionsModule.forChild()` in both main app module and child layout module, but nothing worked.

*Code snippets:*
**app.module.ts**

```
import { AuthService } from './../services/auth.service';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared';
import { NgxPermissionsModule, NgxRolesService } from 'ngx-permissions';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**layout.module.ts**

```
import { NgxPermissionsModule, NgxRolesService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        LayoutRoutingModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule.forChild(),
    ],
    declarations: [LayoutComponent, SidebarComponent, HeaderComponent],
    providers: [AutoLogoutService]
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

**profile.module.ts**

```
import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProfileRoutingModule } from './profile-routing.module';
import { PageHeaderModule } from '../../shared';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ProfileRoutingModule,
        PageHeaderModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule.forChild(),
    ],
    exports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ProfileComponent]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

**layout.component.ts** - This file loads permissions array.

```
constructor(
        public authService: AuthService,
        public router: Router,
        private ngxRolesService: NgxRolesService,
        private location: Location,
        private ngxPermissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
      ) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        const permArray = new Array();
        const role = this.currentUser.roles;
        role.forEach(element => {
          const permission = element.permissions;
          permission.forEach(obj => {
            this.ngxPermissionsService.addPermission(obj.permissionName);
            permArray.push(obj.permissionName);
          });
        });

        this.ngxRolesService.addRole('current-user-role', permArray);
        this.ngxPermissionsService.loadPermissions(permArray);
        localStorage.setItem('lastAction', Date.now().toString());
        console.log('Last Action Time -- ' + localStorage.getItem('lastAction'));
        console.log('Permissions Array -- ' + permArray);
      }
```

Please let me know how can I resolve the error.

**Update:**
Compilation issue was solved using Marius answer. But ngx-permissions functionality is neither working for routing using `NgxPermissionsGuard` nor for elements using `*ngxPermissionsOnly`

**layout-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule',
                canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
                data: {
                    permissions: {
                        only: 'abcd',
                        redirectTo: '/exceptions'
                    }
                }
            },
         ]
       }
    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule {}
```

**profile.component.html**
My permissions array contains permissions 'change-password-self' which is added to ngxpermissions using

```
this.ngxRolesService.addRole('current-user-role', permArray);
this.ngxPermissionsService.loadPermissions(permArray);
```

and `profile.component.html` contains
`<button *ngxPermissionsOnly="['change-password-selfish']" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="togglePasswordView()">Change Password</button>`
So, this button should not be displayed but it is still visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**app.module.ts** imports: [...NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()...]

No need to add NgxPermissionsModule in exports

**layout.module.ts** imports: [...NgxPermissionsModule.forChild()...]

**profile.module.ts** imports: [...NgxPermissionsModule.forChild()...]

".." being the other imports you have.

If this doesn't work for you, post the errors please.

Comment: Please check updated question above. Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: Issue resolved now. Updated ngx-permissions package from version 4.1.0 to 6.0.2 as my application is based on Angular 6.